# Sailsjs model keeps deleting my table content

Tags: sails.js

I am using two DB both mysql.
The default one is for storing the app data.
The second one is to read previously entered data from another application I built (PHP).

My config.models.migrate is set to 'alter'.
My model to read data has migrate: 'safe'.

In my mind it my model's migrate should've overwrite the models.js default migrate but it doesn't.
I don't want my non default table to be wiped out everytime sails lifts because that DB is from a PHP application which needs it.

I need this model just to retrieve data from it not write. 
How can I prevent sails running the default auto migrate?
Currently it works if I set the config.models.migrate to safe but this is not OK.

I need though to allow sails alter the default DB;
So, default datastore alter yes, the second datastore alter no.

Appreciate your time to read this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SailsV1 does not support setting the migration on each model. You can only set your migration default app wide.

Note the third bullet point:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?choosing-an-approach

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks for the reply,  but why then is it allowed to have a per model migration setting? And what should one do in a situation like mine when you need to allow sails to alter the tables of a database but not the tables of a second database?

Comment: Try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-migrations (with safe mode always one for development and production)